# Is this still considered a valid CSV file?

Tags: excel, csv

Let's say I've got a .CSV file with this content:

```
"Name","Values"
"Full Name","David Grey"
"Phone Number","323435454"
"ID","3f21a543cd213b4"
```

As you can see, it's using `"`s even though there are no `\r\n` values, os `,`s in these cells. Is this why Excel is showing it incorrectly?

```
Name,"Values"
Full Name,"David Grey"
Phone Number,"323435454"
ID,"3f21a543cd213b4"
```

Every row is shown in one column, `R1` where R = Row ID.

I'm generating this file in C# with a custom method. Should I add an `if` that checks if the cell contains `,`s, and add `"` only then?

Comment: Is excel showing it with the double quotes like in the second sample?

Comment: When you step through the import wizard do you see any chance to control how it handles columns?

Comment: You may want to add condition to your c# code when generating the output data, otherwise Excel defaults to interpret this as a string literal with enclosed comma (one cell) rather than multiple values (2+ cells). The quotes are generally used to define a string literal that includes commas.

Comment: Okay, I;ll do that when I'll get home.